# Calculating area relative to the y-axis

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I was asked to calculate the area of the region bounded by the following graph:
$$ y = x^2+4x ; y=0$$
I substituted $y$ in order to get $x = 0$ 0r $x=4$. Now I would like a little bit of help to get the expression that I must integrate and the limits of the integral with respect to $y$ please.

Comment: If it is $x^2+4x$, then we cross the $x$-axis at $x=-4$ and $x=0$. Draw a picture and what to do may become clearer.

Comment: I agree, but how should I proceed from there? which $y$ values would be the limits of integration?

Comment: It is $x$-values, $x=-4$ to $x=0$.

Comment: But I am integrating relative to the $y$ axis.

Comment: I do not see why you would want to do that, it makes the problem more complicated.  Or does the problem explicitly ask you to suffer and integrate with respect to $y$?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am required to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding the area by integration with respect to $y$ is not the reasonable thing to do. But if you *really were* asked to do it that way, here's how.

Draw a picture. The function $y=x^2+4x$ reaches a minimum at $x=-2$. The minimum **value** is $-4$.  We want to find the area of the region below $y=0$ and above $y=x^2+4x$.  This is a parabolic segment cut off by the $x$-axis.

For a $y$ between $-4$ and $0$, draw a thin horizontal strip of width "$dy$."

We find the approximate area of that strip.  So we want to find the length of the strip.  Solve for $x$ in terms of $y$. We have $x^2+4x-y=0$, and therefore by the Quadratic Formula,
$$x=-2\pm \sqrt{4+y}.$$
The length of the strip is therefore $(-2+\sqrt{4+y})-(-2-\sqrt{4+y})$, which is $2\sqrt{4+y}$.

So the area of the strip is approximately $2\sqrt{4+y}\,dy$. For the full area of our region, "add up" (integrate) from $y=-4$ to $y=0$. The area is
$$\int_{-4}^0 2\sqrt{4+y}\,dy.$$

**Remark:** Much easier is to integrate with respect to $x$. We get $\int_{-4}^0 (0-(x^2+4x))\,dx$.

However one does it, the area is $\frac{32}{3}$.